# IPv6 to IPv4 inter-conversion in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipv6, applet, ipv4

I have a list of IP's in IPv4 format that i have collected from previous HttpRequest objects that my web-server received. I have a java applet which gives IP addresses in Ipv6 format(java applet returns a bunch of data along with the IP address). I need to check if the IP returned by the applet matches any item from list.

How do inter-convert IPv6 and IPv4 formats?

My web application is built on **ASP.Net C#**

**EDIT**

here is the problem that i am facing. The Java applet returns a bunch of IP's from the client which i assume depends on the number of network cards the client machine has.

Along with this i get a IP address from the ASP.Net HTTPRequest object. I need to find out which IP was actually used to connect to my website and carryout some tasks.

The problem is sometimes i  get only one IP  from the javaapplet in IPv6 format where as the IP i get from the HTTPRequest object is in IPv4 format so the comparison fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are talking about IPv4-IPv6 mapping or IPv4 address embedding.

> IPv4 address embedding is used to
>   create a relationship between an IPv4
>   address and an IPv6 address to aid in
>   the transition from IPv4 to IPv6. One
>   type, the IPv4-compatible IPv6
>   address, is used for devices that are
>   compatible with both IPv4 and IPv6; it
>   begins with 96 zero bits. The other,
>   the IPv4-mapped address, is used for
>   mapping IPv4 devices that are not
>   compatible with IPv6 into the IPv6
>   address space; it begins with 80
>   zeroes followed by 16 ones.

..

> The difference between these two kinds of addresses is subtle, but
>   important. The first 80 bits are
>   always zero, so when this is seen you
>   know it is an embedded IPv4 address of
>   some sort. IPv4-compatible IPv6
>   addresses are only used for devices
>   that are actually IPv6-aware; the
>   IPv4-compatible address is in addition
>   to its conventional IPv6 address. In
>   contrast, if the "FFFF" is seen for
>   the 16 bits after the initial 80, this
>   designates a conventional IPv4 devices
>   whose IPv4 address has been mapped
>   into the IPv6 format. It is not an
>   IPv6-capable device.

So the bottom line is unless they are mapped together, you won't be able to convert to/from. You'd need a [translator](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~mef/research/napt/reports/usenix98/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

0A0D already seemed to answer this, but I'll give it a shot:

If the first 10 bytes (80 bits) of your IPv6 address are zero, then you can compare the last 4 bytes with the 4 bytes of an IPv4 address.

```
bool AreEquivalent(IPAddress ip6addr, IPAddress ip4addr)
{
  byte[] ip6bytes = ip6addr.GetBytes();
  byte[] ip4bytes = ip4addr.GetBytes();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
     if (ip6bytes[i] != 0)
       return false;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     if (ip6bytes[i + 12] != ip4bytes[i])
        return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This assumes that you already know what is ipv6 and ipv4. Add extra logic as appropriate if you need to compare arbitrary addresses.

Comment: The code above doesn't seem complete. According to the [standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3513), in addition to the above, you also need to check bytes 10 and 11 on the IPv6 address. They need to be 0 for an "IPv4-compatible IPv6 address" and FF for "IPv4-mapped IPv6 address".

Answer (score 2):

Assume you working with some kind of wireless platform or has the capability to do wireless.
IPV6 has to do with improvement on mobile networking AKA "Wireless". Converting a IPV6 to a IPV4 is not what you are looking for. IPV6 is a real address. It is the new Advanced standard for IP Addresses these days. Take a look [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102847/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071807-1.aspx) and decide for yourself.  You can also do it manually [here](http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/ipv4-to-ipv6-converter.php). IPV6 is supposed to mask your IPV4.

Hope that helps.